# Unable to bind my fake array to a scope variable in my test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, karma-runner

I'm unable to bind my fake array to a scope variable in my directive test.

My test:

```
describe('Directive: report - section', function () {

  // load the directive's module
  beforeEach(module('ReportApp'));
  beforeEach(module('Templates')); // The external template file referenced by templateUrl

  var element, scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
  }));


  it('should have 1 section available', inject(function ($compile) {

    var testSections = [
        {
            id: 'Example01',
            visible: true,
            img: 'image1.jpg'
        },
        {
            id: 'Example02',
            visible: false,
            img: 'image2.jpg'
        }
    ];

    scope.sections = testSections;
    element = angular.element('<section></section>');
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    expect(element.find('li').length).toEqual(1);

  }));


});
```

My directive:

```
angular.module('ReportApp')
  .directive('section', function (report, reportStatus) {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'src/report/views/parts/section.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: function( $scope, $element, $attrs){

        var sections = report.getDatabase().sections;

        $scope.sections = sections;
        reportStatus.setActiveSection(sections[0]);

      },

      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

      }

    };
  });
```

My test result:

```
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Mac OS X 10.9.2) Directive: report - section should have 1 section available FAILED
  Expected 4 to equal 1.
  Error: Expected 4 to equal 1.
      at null.<anonymous> (/Users/user/MyAPPs/temp/report/app/src/report/directives/tests/spec/section.js:77:39)
      at Object.invoke (/Users/user/MyAPPs/temp/report/app/vendor/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3678:17)
      at workFn (/Users/user/MyAPPs/temp/report/app/vendor/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2102:20)
```

My problem is that the fake sections(testSections) are not being applied. So, this result "Expected 4 to equal 1" is due to the original sections that are being used instead my fake one.

Why this scope does not work ?

```
scope.sections = testSections;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is your `scope.sections = testSections;` is replaced by `$scope.sections = sections;` in your directive code.

In this case, you have to spy your `report.getDatabase()` to return your `testSections`

```
describe('Directive: report - section', function () {

  // load the directive's module
  beforeEach(module('ReportApp'));
  beforeEach(module('Templates')); // The external template file referenced by templateUrl

  var element, scope, report;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope,_report_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    report = _report_; //inject the report object and store in a variable
  }));


  it('should have 1 section available', inject(function ($compile) {

    var testSections = [
        {
            id: 'Example01',
            visible: true,
            img: 'image1.jpg'
        },
        {
            id: 'Example02',
            visible: false,
            img: 'image2.jpg'
        }
    ];

    spyOn(report,"getDatabase").and.returnValue({ sections : testSections });//spy the getDatabase function
    //we just need a stub, so we could also write this:

    //report.getDatabase = function (){
    //       return { sections : testSections };
    //}

    element = angular.element('<section></section>');
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    expect(element.find('li').length).toEqual(1);

  }));


});
```

Comment: Hi @Khanh-to I could not make it work so far. It returns me an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'returnValue' of undefined.

Comment: But it make no sense, since that If I console.log('_report_: ', _report_); show me all the object properly.

Comment: @Ventura: what is your jasmine version?

Comment: @Ventura: in this case, we actually don't need jasmine. You could try the code I commented

Comment: @Ventura: If you use jasmine 1.3, try `spyOn(report,"getDatabase").andReturn({ sections : testSections });`